# OpenSUSE: Find all Packages without a repository

Tags: package-management, opensuse, repository, yast, zypper

I just upgraded to OpenSUSE 12.2 from OpenSUSE 12.1 by changing all of my repositories to target 12.2 (instead of 12.1). Now that I've upgraded, I've found a bunch of packages that have no repository*, which the **YaST Software Manager** marks with red text in the version column. I can scroll through these and remove every single one, but I'm wondering if the **zypper** search (`zypper se`) or the **Software Manager** has any way to target/select all of these at once.

*- These packages had a repository (OpenSUSE 12.1 something), but since I replaced those repositories with the 12.2 repositories, they no longer have a repository association. This doesn't create a problem, because the 12.2 repositories should contain everything I need to run my system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Martin's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/53522/13308)/guidance, I wrote a quick script to take a string of packages to remove, `zremove.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh

pkgs=""
while read line
do
        pkgs="$pkgs $line"
done

zypper rm $pkgs
```

After noticing that all of my packages "without a repository" had a distribution of **openSUSE 12.1** in the **rpm** query, I issued this command to locate and remove all of them:

```
rpm -qa --qf '%{DISTRIBUTION} : %{NAME}\n' | grep "openSUSE 12.1 :" | sed 's/openSUSE 12.1 : //' | sudo zremove.sh
```

This doesn't generally answer the question of how to find all packages without a backing repository, but it did solve my initial issue.

Answer (score 5):

```
rpm -qa --qf '%-30{DISTRIBUTION} %{NAME}\n'| sort
```

gives you a list of all repos used by your packages. Finding the ones you don't want is left as an exercise to the reader. `:-)`.

Answer (score 2):

Packages that have 'lost' their repository or were installed directly from a .rpm file will show `Repository: @System` when you do a `zypper info` on them. So in theory it should be possible to find them all with a `zypper packages --repo @System --installed-only` but this is still missing in libzypp ([openSUSE Bug 770239 - 'zypper pa' lacks support for @System repo](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=770239)).

As a workaround one has to do a `zypper info` on each installed package and filter for those who have the repository `@System`:

```
rpm -qa --queryformat="%{n}\n" | while read p; do zypper info $p | grep -q '^Repository: @System' && echo $p; done
```

Quite slow but does the job.

Answer (score 0):

On newer OpenSuSE releases,

```
$ zypper pa --orphaned
```

does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The following command lists all installed packages which do not have a referenced repository anymore or are installed via `rpm` directly:

`LC_ALL=C zypper pa --installed | awk '$0 ~ /^i/ && $3 == "@System" {print $5}'`